# Spark: How to efficiently have intersections preserving duplicates (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, similarity, rdd, set-intersection

I have 2 RDDs, each of which is a set of strings containing duplicates. I want to find the intersection of the two sets *preserving duplicates*. Example:

`RDD1 : a, b, b, c, c, c, c`

`RDD2 : a, a, b, c, c`

The intersection I want is the set `a, b, c, c` i.e. the intersection would contain each element the minimum amount of times that it is present in both the sets.

The default `intersection` transformation does not preserve duplicates AFAIK. Is there a way to *efficiently* compute the intersection using some other transformations and/or the intersection transformation? I'm trying to avoid doing it algorithmically, which is unlikely to be as efficient as doing it the Spark way. (For the interested, I'm trying to compute [Jaccard bag similarity](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf) for a set of files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing a little from the implementation of `intersection`, you could do something like:

```
(val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")))
(val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "a", "b", "c", "c")))

val cogrouped = rdd1.map(k => (k, null)).cogroup(rdd2.map(k => (k, null)))
val groupSize = cogrouped.map { case (key, (buf1, buf2)) => (key, math.min(buf1.size, buf2.size)) }
val finalSet = groupSize.flatMap { case (key, size) => List.fill(size)(key) }

(finalSet.collect = Array(a, b, c, c))
```

This works because `cogroup` will maintain duplicate occurrences of values of a pair for each grouping (in this case, all of your nulls). Also note that we are doing no more shuffles here than we would have with the original use of `intersection`.

Comment: Great - thanks! There's a minor syntax error - Edited `iter1` => `buf1` and `iter2=>buf2` to get it working.

Comment: Also, I've a query - When do you use `parallelize` explicitly vs expect Spark to handle it internally via the RDDs?

Comment: You are correct -- sorry about that. The `parallelize()` method actually loads an existing collection into an RDD versus say the `textFile()` method which loads files from disk into an RDD.